# How come my code doesn't run properly when there are no errors?

Tags: visual-studio

I'm faced with a problem where my codes have no errors but when I run the page pops up on my browser but it says the localhost can't be found. Since there are no errors, I don't know what is wrong with it and don't know how to fix it. So far, I don't think it is because of a setup problem.

Could someone give me possible reasons why this is happening? Thank you very much.